# How to remote control macOS from windows 10 through port 3293

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-control, remote-assistance

I've googled and know that we could remote control MacOS using VNC applications (through port 5900), but in my company, they blocked VNC apps (due to some security concern). So I wonder whether we can remote control MacOS from Windows through port 3283? Is there any apps support it?

---

EDIT: I don't intend to bypass my company policy, they don't block 3283 port, they only block port 5900. but I can't find any application that run on 3283

Comment: I’m afraid we cannot help you to bypass your company ‘s IT policy. You need to ask them.

Comment: @Tetsujin They don't block 3283, they only block 5900, but I can't find any application that help remote through 3283